# Redirecting and then moving target file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, file-descriptors

I tested the following on AIX and it works.

```
logfile=log.txt
echo "Hello" > "$logfile"
exec 1>>"$logfile"
mv "$logfile" "${logfile}_new"
echo "World"
```

After this script ran the file `log.txt_new` will contain:

```
Hello
World
```

I was not expecting it to work because I renamed the file to where `stdout` was being redirected. Why does it work?

It also works if I mv/rename the directory that contains the log file.

Comment: The other question's title says Linux, but this behaviour is common to Unix-like systems

Comment: Renaming (or moving, deleting) an opened file doesn't affect the process that had opened the file: its file-operations use a file-handle, not the file-name.